# Jquery - How do you get checkbox values from closest parent only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, parent-child, closest

I am working on a school assignment and we are starting to learn Jquery

I am looking to collect the values from a set of check boxes but only the ones that fall within the div that the button that triggers the function is contained within.

So far I have been able to get the values, but if any of the boxes are checked in the other divs those values are added as well because they need to all share the same name. I am trying to avoid duplicating code.

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var destination = $(this).closest('.destinations'); //this selects the div the button is in but I can't figure out how to apply it to the checkbox value gathering
        var base_price = $(destination).find('.base_price').text();
        var add_ons = [];
        $.each($("input[name='add_on']:checked"), function(){ //I player around with using the variable destination somewhere here but am thinking there needs to be another step
            add_ons.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).remove();
        console.log(base_price)
        console.dir(add_ons) //the values are successfully added but I can't figure out how to isolate based on the the variable 'destination'
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class = "destinations">
    <h2>New York, New York</h2>
    <img src="images/newyork.jpeg">
    <p>
        Includes: 5 Night Hotel Stay, Central Park Tours, and New York Skyscrapers Package<br>
        Starting at $<span class="base_price">1299.99</span>
    </p>
    <div>
        <h3>Add-Ons</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="add_on" value="1000">
        <label for="option1"> Add Two-Night Stay at the Ritz</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="add_on" value="200">
        <label for="option2"> Broadway Show</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="add_on" value="400">
        <label for="option3"> New York Steakhouse Gourmet Night Out</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id = "nyny">Get price</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="destinations">
    <h2>Paris, France</h2>
    <img src="images/eiffel_tower.jpeg">
    <p>
        Includes: 5 Night Hotel Stay, 3 Museum Package, and Taste of France Tour<br>
        Starting at $<span class="base_price">1699.99</span>
    </p>
    <div>
    <h3>Add-Ons</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="add_on" value="1000">
    <label for="option1"> 3 day Vineyards and Flowers Tour</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="add_on" value="200">
    <label for="option2"> Visit the Eiffel Tower</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="add_on" value="400">
    <label for="option3"> Meet President Macron</label><br>
    </div> 
     <button id = "paris">Get Price</button>
 </div>
<div class = "destinations">
    <h2>Tokyo, Japan</h2>
    <img src="images/tokyo.jpeg">
    <p>
        Includes: 5 Night Hotel Stay, Build a Pokemon Event, and a Bonsai Class<br>
        Starting at $<span class="base_price">1199.99</span>
    </p>
    <div>
    <h3>Add-Ons</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="add_on" value="1000">
    <label for="option1"> Wagyu Steak Dinner at Aragawa</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="add_on" value="200">
    <label for="option2"> Random Japanese Game Show Night!</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="add_on" value="400">
    <label for="option3"> Mount Fuji Adventure</label><br>
    </div>
    <button id = "japan">Get Price</button>
</div>
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try this code. 
destination.each($("input[name='add_on']:checked"), function(){
       add_ons.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: @JakirHossen `$.fn.each()` expects a function as argument

Comment: Really doesn't make sense that there are multiple checkboxes with same name and it not being a `[]` array name. The name doesn't match the html from your previous question either. Always provide enough html in question to make this a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: destination.find("input[name='add_on']:checked")).each(function(){ 
            add_ons.push($(this).val());
        });

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I added the HTML. Charlie could you please explain what you mean about it not being an array name? Is that about something different than `add_ons = [];` ? I used the same name for each because that was a method of checking checked box values I had found when I looked it up. Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should only select checkbox within that parent div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var destination = $(this).closest('.destinations'); // selecting the div container
        var base_price = $(destination).find('.base_price').text();
        var add_ons = [];
        //$(destination) selects the parent div and find() function finds checkbox within that div.
        $(destination).find("input[name='add_on']:checked")).each(function(){ 
            add_ons.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).remove();
        console.log(base_price)
        console.dir(add_ons);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Note that `destination` is already a jQuery object. No need to wrap it again in `$()`

Comment: This works! Thank you Biki and, again thank you charlie for popping in and the note about the wrapper here.